# Google Cloud Storage with google-api-client-php and JSON credential but got 403 error after awhile

Tags: php, sdk, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-403

I am tring to use Google Cloud Storage service by google-api-client-php SDK with JSON credential, and applying the example code like:

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Storage::DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$ret = $storage->buckets->listBuckets("project-id");
```

However, these codes are okay after first few hours I create the credential, but I keep receive 'permission denied' error with same code/credential file few hours later.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

I have not idea if this is a code level or service level problem...

Comment: Is it possible that you are using a service account that is not a member of the project with "project-id"?

Comment: No. This service account is created by project owner and this service account is valid in first few hours after creation.

Comment: Can you check whether the service account has permissions on the bucket/object?

Comment: I think default bucket permissions are granted to all project owners, isn't it? And I am commencing list bucket operation. Also, this error is happen suddenly, same code/credential are working fine until few hours later of create of service account.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your service account has the right permissions in GCP:

In the console, go to:

Api Manager > Credentials > Manage Service Accounts > Permissions > Add Member

On the pop-up screen, paste your service account's email address and give it "can edit" access. That should do it.